# How to Trigger a PCIe Non-CTO Non-Fatal Error?

Tags: c, linux, intel, pci-e

I've been utilizing the einj tool to inject a Non-Fatal PCIe error with CTO. However, for my specific requirements, I'm looking to induce an error with the TLP Header, specifically either a POISON_TLP or MALF_TLP error.

I'm aware of aer-inject, but it isn't what I'm seeking as it only offers software simulation. Could someone suggest any tools or methodologies to effectively induce these specific PCIe errors?